# How can I set my own tick labels in ggplot while plotting factor values of time series?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I am plotting some time series in `ggplot` and on the x axis I got some date/time data. Data from 2008 to 2016. The problem is that dates are not continuous and for instance the last date of 2008 is

2008/05/14 19:05:12

and the next date is for 2009 something like this

2009/03/24 10:17:54

While plotting these, the result is the following

[image]

In order to get rid of the empty spaces I turn my dates into factors
`dates <- factors(dates)` in order to get the correct plot.
[image]
But after that I am unable to set the x tick labels as they don't change using

`scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,1724,2283,5821,8906,10112,10156,14875 ),
 labels = c("2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015"))`

How can I change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems this is throwing up, and the solution will really depend on what you're looking for. I'd suggest you post up some sample data and your code so far to get a more precise answer, but here's a possibility in the mean time:

Your graph above is not showing a continuous scale (though it may look like it), it's a discrete scale with the number of levels corresponding to unique date observations. Two problems come out of this:

- applying a `scale_x_continuous` wont work, as the year breaks wont be evenly spread
- your data looks like it's smoothly spread, but it isn't, which isn't a good principle for visualisation.

If what you're trying to do is show change year-by-year you could sort all of your data into yearly 'bins' and plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# creating random data

df <- tibble(date = as_datetime(runif(1000, as.numeric(as_datetime("2001/01/24 09:30:43")), as.numeric(as_datetime("2006/02/24 09:30:43")))))

df["val"] <- rnorm(nrow(df), 25, 5)

# use lubridate to extract year as new variable, and plot grouped years
df %>%
  mutate(year = factor(year(date))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, val)) +
  geom_point(position = "jitter")
```

[image]

Another possibility could be to use a colour scale to note your groupings by year, keeping all the dates in order but removing the gaps (and therefore not using a continuous x-axis scale):

```
df %>%  # begin by simulating a data 'gap'
  filter(date>as_datetime("2003/07/24 09:30:43")|date<as_datetime("2002/09/24 09:30:43")) %>% 
  mutate(year = factor(year(date)),  # 'year' to select colour
         date = factor(date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, val, col = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),  # removes all ticks and labels, as too many unique times
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

If neither of those are helpful do comment below with any clarifications of what you're looking for, and I'll see if I can help!

**Edit:** One last idea, you could create an invisible series of points which act as the breaks for your axis ticks:

```
blank_labels <- tibble(date = as_datetime(c("20020101 000000",
                                          "20030101 000000",
                                          "20040101 000000",
                                          "20050101 000000",
                                          "20060101 000000")),
                       col = "NA", val = 0)

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(date>as_datetime("2003/07/24 09:30:43")|date<as_datetime("2002/09/24 09:30:43")) %>% 
  mutate(col = "black") %>% 
  bind_rows(blank_labels) %>% 
  mutate(date_fac = factor(date)) 

tick_values <- left_join(blank_labels, df2, by = c("date", "col"))

df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date_fac, val, col = col)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = tick_values$date_fac, labels = c("2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006")) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty helpful:

Plotting with `position="jitter" ` didn't get the job done because the data set is pretty big.

Using color by year seems to be a great idea, although it looks weird, considering it's a time series

The last option is what I also tried and it seems to work the best